# Is there a "break even point" or life cycle analysis directory or calculator that's kept up to date?

Tags: life-cycle-analysis, defining-sustainability, internet, embodied-energy

I've seen plenty of one-time calculations dedicated to one specific thing (usually plastic vs metal straws, or reusable vs disposable cups) but don't know of any organizations or even blogs that aggregate information for multiple comparisons AND regularly update it. What would be even better is something customizable that would let me plug in information like the fact that I generally use a paper towel 2-3x before throwing it out, but tend to wash rags/towels after only one use. Also things like whether something actually gets recycled or biodegrades, so the calculations are actually representative.

Comment: If you google [life cycle analysis](https://www.google.com/search?q=life+cycle+analysis+database) you'll find quite a few results. Here are [64 free results for "paper"](https://nexus.openlca.org/search/query=paper!Price=%3C10!Country=United%20States) from OpenLCA.

Comment: I looked through those but neither really have what I'm asking for. I'm looking for something like this, where you can adjust parameters and draw from a pool of products https://www.capterra.com/